# How to compare Matlab OptmizationExpression's?

Tags: matlab, mixed-integer-programming

I'm solving a binary integer linear program (BILP).  To generate the optimization expression, I take the dot product of vector of decision variables with the vector of each decision's value.  The two different ways of generating the dot product yield identical looking optimization expressions, but there doesn't seem to be a way to confirm that they are identical.

```
Tdecisions = table;

% Binary decision variables
Tdecisions.YesNo = optimvar( 'YesNo' , 2,1 , ...
   'Type','integer' , 'LowerBound',0 , 'UpperBound',1 );

% Utility/value coefficients for each decision
Tdecisions.VALUE = [ 1 ; 2 ];

% The two ways to get dot product should yield the same result
x = Tdecisions.YesNo' * Tdecisions.VALUE
y = dot( Tdecisions.YesNo , Tdecisions.VALUE )
%
% Output is:
%   x = Linear OptimizationExpression YesNo(1) + 2*YesNo(2)
%   y = Linear OptimizationExpression YesNo(1) + 2*YesNo(2)

% isequaln returns false, so it isn't up to the task
isequaln( x, y )

% Text expressions of OptmizationExpressions are identical (diff).
% This is not convenient.
writeexpr(x,'x.txt')
writeexpr(y,'y.txt')
```

Since I'm new to Matlab's Problem Based Flow for Mixed Integer Linear programs (MILPs), I thought that such a sanity check might be important for industry sized problems: Is there a way to check equivalence of OptmizationExpressions on the fly without resorting to generation of external text file for comparison?

I am using Matlab 2019a.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, the expression `x-y` yields `Expression with all zero coefficients` if they are equal.  I think this question might still save some time for someone looking to do the same thing, for the similar reasons.  However, if no one thinks anyone else might want to do this, I can delete the question.

Comment: i would recommend to keep it as there will always be someone with the same issue. But please make an answer out of the comment and accept it so everyone knows the question is solved

Comment: Actually, it's not a full solution.  It is only good for interactive
use because the user can see the message that is displayed. It’s not
clear how Matlab code can check for an all-zero
OptimizationExpression.  I've asked TMW if there a way to check, one
that returns a Boolean true/false.  And if not, then can this feature
request be made.  Justification: The ability to programmatically test
for all-zeros in `x-y` is the only way of which I know to check for
equivalence between x and y.